# Jquery OWL Carousel just doesn't seem to work, divs are put beneath each other

Tags: jquery, owl-carousel

I'm building a website for a school project, but my Owl Carousel slider doesn't work. Could someone please help me, because I don't understand why it doesn't work. I've tried reading the documentation, but it doesn't help me.

I want create an instance of Owl Carousel, but although I followed the instructions, the different divs are just placed beneath each other. I know this is perhaps a bit vague, but i'm not sure how to put this.

Thank you!

```
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="css/layout.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="owl-carousel/owl.carousel.css" type="text/css">
<link href="owl-carousel/owl.theme.css" type="text/css">
<link href="owl-carousel/owl.transitions.css" type="text/css">

<div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-1">
    <div id="owl-demo" class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
        <div class="item">
            <p class="broodtekst">Hét event van de bedrijfsfilm in Vlaanderen gaat in deze <strong>16e editie</strong> over de taalgrens heen. <br /> Dit jaar organiseren we het  festival in Brussel en dingen naast Vlaamse nu ook Brusselse en Waalse bedrijven mee naar de prestigieuze video awards. <br />
            Het festival zal ingeleid worden met een beurs en allerlei gastsprekers.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <p class="broodtekst">L’evenement du film d’enterprise en flandre changera d’un evenement regional à un evenement national. Depuis cette année on organisera le festival à Kinepolis Bruxelles et l’ont aussi des entreprises bruxellois et wallon l’opportunité de concourir pour ces prix prestigieuses.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="img/groepsfoto.png" alt="The Last of Us" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>    
<script src="owl-carousel/owl.carousel.js"></script>     
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({

        navigation : true,
        slideSpeed : 300,
        paginationSpeed : 400,
        singleItem : true

        // "singleItem:true" is a shortcut for:
        // items : 1, 
        // itemsDesktop : false,
        // itemsDesktopSmall : false,
        // itemsTablet: false,
        // itemsMobile : false

      });
    });
</script>   `

<!-- Hier komt de JQuery -->

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

I've placed it on [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qk05r1g2/), but it doesn't seem to work there either.

You can also visit the site on: http://cvf.kiran.be

Comment: Create your test case with working code-snippet or http://jsfiddle.net and post the link

Comment: 'Doesn't work' is a bit terse. What is the expected outcome?

Answer (score 3):

I've just adjusted your [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qk05r1g2/1/). The Owl Slider is now working, the only adjustment was to change

```
<div id="#owl-demo" class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
```

to

```
<div id="owl-demo" class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
```

In case you don't know - the value of an id-attribute is just written as `value` and referenced by jQuery using the `#` as shortcut for the id attribute. Simplified: the jQuery selector `$("#value")` is the same as the javascript selector `document.geElementById("value")`.
For reference: http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/